# No css in django admin page

Tags: python, css, django

I have just install django 1.7 and recently create new project and application. I have create a new superuser. when I try to login to my superuser account the django administration page appear without css. I do not what's wrong i did. can anyone help me?

Here is my setting.py:

```
 """
Django settings for blog project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '%j$#fj6ddv$nkgv=v4kez6yi56&z$qffzr%gyz6b!ds-!5xi%e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'post',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: are your urls.py pointing to static? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development unrelated tip: if you're starting the project please upgrade to Django 1.8 since it's LTS (Long Term Support)

Answer (score 1):

You should add following to your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
'C:/ProjectPath/static',
]
```

If you have only 1 settings.py file, you should change BASE_DIR value with

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

**In django 1.8 and later**, you should also define a 'templates' folder like 'static'.
Put your html files into "templates" folder and add css/js files like "static/css/bootstrap.css" in your templates(html files).

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: OP is using Django 1.7. `TEMPLATES` were introduced in Django 1.8 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates

Comment: Yes, I solved the same problem with the solution in django 1.9

Comment: Your solution is for a version of Django OP doesn't have. You should edit it for his version or at least recommend him to upgrade